# Wildfly 10 UnmarshalException in empty date tags in the response

Tags: java, jaxb, sax, unmarshalling, wildfly-10

We are migrating our application from Jboss 6 to Wildfly 10, most the web services are running ok, but we are facing a problem with empty date tags in the response from an external web service:

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 784; ]


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseBigInteger(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
at __redirected.__DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(__DatatypeFactory.java:180)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:592)
... 158 more
```

The line and column are the start of the following element

```
...<ADATE><date />...
```

As you can see date is empty and causes the parser to fail (I assume that based on the evidence)

This is a fragment of the WSDL definition for that XML element:

```
   <xsd:element name="ADATE">
      <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="100" type="xsd:date"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
```

We have generated our client classes with Apache CXF 3.1.6 as: wsdl2java -frontend jaxws21 ....

- When using SEIStub implementation the call works for the webservice.
- When using the same code inside of Wildfly it does not work throwing the described exception.
- Is this all info needed?

Is there any way another JAXB implementation that can be configured in Wildfly 10?, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We created an extension of the XmlAdapter and we declared the class in the package-info.java (from the response folder -> "sysrpc", an old cxf) as following:

```
package XXX; 

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import java.util.Date;


public class XMLGregorianCalendarXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, XMLGregorianCalendar>{

@Override
public XMLGregorianCalendar unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    if(v==null ||  v.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(v);
}

@Override
public String marshal(XMLGregorianCalendar v) throws Exception {
    return v==null ? null : /*do something with the XMLGregorianCalendar */;
}

}
```

Then in the package-info.java of the generated classes from wsdl2java command

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters
({
   @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=XXX.XMLGregorianCalendarXmlAdapter.class,type=javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar.class),
   @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=XXX.XMLGregorianCalendarXmlAdapter.class,type=javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar.class)
})
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:external-web-service:SYSRPC")
package YYYY.sysrpc;
```

To debug the communication with an external web service:

in the standalone.xml (located in $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration)

add

```
<property name="org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled" value="true"/>
```

At the end of the system-properties tag

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in XML: tag date is empty, but schema says it has to have some value. Try to write correct date in it.

If you want it to be empty you can write

```
 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

in XML and

```
 nillable="true"
```

in XSD.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in our WSDL but some other people have proposed the same solution, must work "somewhere".